# Increase property value with Maven after each Build

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, build-numbers

This is the script on `build.xml`, in a non maven project, on Netbeans, every time that I "Build", it is increased by 1.

```
<target name="-pre-compile" description="Sets the buildversion for the current build">
<propertyfile file="${src.dir}\recursos\language.properties">
    <entry key="application.buildnumber" value="1" type="int" operation="+"/>
    <entry key="application.builddate" value="now" type="date"/>
</propertyfile>
</target>
```

This is resources file that I use and I want Maven write it too: languange.properties

```
application.title=Software title...
#build version control
application.buildnumber=334
application.builddate=2016/09/07 15\:16
application.version=1
application.icon=/icons/icon.png
```

I already read about mojohaus but doesn't seems to fit what I need.

I know that I have to add a Plugin, with some Executions/Goals tags, but I don't know how to tell Maven that increase that property's value by 1.

Comment: Have you looked in to [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)? That would let you copy in properties defined in the POM to the `language.properties` file, although it doesn't help you with auto-incrementing the build number.  This doesn't really sound like a common Maven use case; are you an environment where this problem could be better solved on a CI server of some kind?

Comment: checked and no, with filtering is not possible to do this.
I don't what exactly has to do a CI server with this, just one person really build and increase the buildnumber, before release the new version, 1.334, 1.335... other contributors doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I successfully implemented it:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <id>read-props</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>src/main/resources/build.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>write-props</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>src/main/resources/build.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-dynamic-properties</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
                                project.properties.buildnumber = (project.properties.buildnumber.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                        </source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- debug print out, to be removed afterwards -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="${buildnumber}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What we are actually doing:

- We are using the `properties-maven-plugin` to read a file (via its [`read-projet-properties`](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html) goal) from a file, `src/main/resources/build.properties` in the `initialize` phase, hence really early in the default build cycle
- Now, the `buildnumber` property has been pulled from the file and part of our build. During the same phase, we use the `gmave-plugin` to increment its value via a small script.
- Then during the `generate-resources` phase (as an example) we [write](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/write-project-properties-mojo.html) the new value of `buildnumber` (override) to the same file, for the next future iteration. This step is fundamental, since we need to store the state somewhere and it should be under version control, that is, part of the project. The `src/main/resources` is probably not the best choice since it will be packaged with the application (you can always skip it), so you can store it on some other file (but still it should be part of the versioned project).
- Then, as a debug/proof, the `antrun` will print the current `buildnumber` value.

To make it work, the initial value of the `buildnumber` property in the `build.properties` file should be set a 0 (the property must exist upfront). However this file would also risk to be continuously in conflict being under version control, that's why the whole behaviour should be wrapped into a maven profile and used only in certain cases (e.g. the team leader during a release). This constraint would actually lead to a more standard approach: let a CI server handle the whole mechanism, not maven.

Side note: unfortunately, the `properties-maven-plugin` doesn't provide much configuration, it will always read and write all the build properties, which is harmless in most of the case although not optimal. Better would be to have an include/exclude mechanism to filter and only read/write the `buildnumber` property.

Comment: I don't understand where is pointing this:

`project.properties.buildnumber = project.properties.buildnumber.toInteger() + 1).toString();`


What is project? a variable? like ${project.basedir}?

Comment: it's the groovy way to get to Maven elements, sugar. Basically, via `project` (the Maven `project` element), you get to access the `properties` (that is, the element, but also the runtime object in the Maven model of the build) and you increment it. You can only use this notation in this plugin, not anywhere you would like in the `pom.xml`

Comment: This is almost what I wanted.
The problem is (as you said it)  that rewrite the entire .properties files, and in my case I use this for i18n too with the suffix _en_US, _es_AR  etc..
anyway.. Thanks so much